# Do we have a generic proxy template class (with customization points) somewhere?

Tags: c++, c++17, proxy-pattern

With a healthy dose of [fear for reinventing the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) - im looking for a generic template for a proxy like object that will help me customize the constructor - a very basic and unfinished sketch look like this:

```
template<class T>
struct proxy {
  proxy( ? ) {<customized init of elem_ - possible two-phase calling init(), etc. >}
  T& operator*() {return elem_;}
private:
  T elem_;
};
```

Normally you would implement different access mechanics, etc., etc. which becomes easy to get wrong / or just not very future-proof.

In this case i just need to customize the construction of the object (which can't be copied and is the reason why in this case, such a proxy would be helpfull). Though often for proxy pattern it is the access that is customized. In a pinch, a "lazy construction template" would also solve it.

Comment: What's the advantage over adding an additional constructor?

Comment: @super OP probably cannot change the definition of that type.

Comment: Does your custom "initialization" need to mutate the object after it is actually initialized, as you wrote? Otherwise, C++17's copy elision makes a plain factory function work just fine.

Comment: @Quentin it does mutate - so cannot 'exploit' copy elision.